# Cuda performance problem

Tags: cuda, thrust

maybe this question is a little too general but maybe someone has experience the same problem.

I have a small cuda program using thrust and everything is fine. It works as expected.

But when I port the same program to another machine the performance of the whole program is about 10 to 100 times slower than the original machine. The hardware of the second machine should be faster (GTX480 instead of GTX265), so I guess the problem is on the second machine itsself. Does anyone has an idea what might go wrong?

Comment: I think I found the solution. One has to compile with --arch=sm_20 on the GTX480 device. I used --arch=sm_13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, --arch=sm_20 solved the problem.